# problem with oci_bind_by_name

Tags: php, oracle

i cant understand length and type please anyone explain it to me
$rc = oci_bind_by_name($statement, $bindvarname, $phpvariable, $length, $type)

Answer (score 0):

see [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual White Paper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/026973.pdf) page 147.